# What is this game that's similar to Go?

Tags: identify-this-game, go

I always thought that **Go** was played by trying to place 5 of your pieces in a row while blocking your opponent from doing so, but I just recently looked up the rules, and it's completely different.

Is the game I was playing real? What is its name?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are two strong possibilities that are both played on a 19x19 board, **Pente** and **Go Moku**. Both have as a goal to get 5 in a row.  Pente also allows capturing and you can win by capturing 5 pairs of stones.

**[Pente](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1295/pente)**

[image]

Pretty good game, I had it confused with **Go** for the longest time as well.  There have been a bunch of editions over the years, you shouldn't have any trouble finding a set.

Comment: please note that it is completely different from Go, but : "Go" in Japanese also means "Five", so that is why it is part of the "Go Moku" name, and the board used is also similar to a goban (probably because it allows one to reuse an existing set). The rules (and the gameplay) are completely different though.. And I think you meant "13x13 board" ?

Comment: I seem to recall from [_The Master of Go_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Master_of_Go) by Yasunari Kawabata that the Go professionals – or at least the rather obsessive older player, the eponymous master – played [Go Moku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gomoku) (and maybe other games like [shogi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shogi)) between games for relaxation.

Answer (score 14):

I think the name of your game is Go Moku. That is the "five in a row" game.

It's not really similar to Go, except in terms of the name. It can, however, be played on a Go board with black and white stones.

But the objectives and criteria for winning are totally different.